# OpenXML How to insert an "ID" for each paragraph?

Tags: xslt, openxml, identifier, paragraph

I'm trying to manually create docx files. In fact, I create the file "document.xml" with an XSL Transformation from an XML file data.

I'll need to convert my docx into xml data file in the future. *So I need to put identifiers in each paragraph*. I tried naively to put my own "id" attribute on a , but of course Word removes it.

Do you have any idea how I could identify my elements of in this docx xml?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You could try using aliased sdt blocks for paragraph identifiers.